# Issues evaluating a Fourier transform on a restriction.

Tags: fourier-transform

The F.T. of the function $R^3\rightarrow R \ -U(x,y,z)\ $ is:
$$g(k_{1},k_{2},k_{3})=\iiint_{R^{3}} U(x,y,z)e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y+ k_3 z)}dxdydz$$
By putting $z=0$ in the previous equation, you obtain:
$$g(k_{1},k_{2},k_{3})=\iiint_{R^{3}} U(x,y,0)e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y)}dxdydz=$$
$$=\iint_{R^{2}} U(x,y,0)e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y)}dxdy\int _{R}dz$$
Now,I don't know how to deal with the last integral $\int _{R}dz$. Since previously I have put z=0 then it should be dz=0 and also $\int _{R}dz =0 $. However in this case it results $g(k_{1},k_{2},k_{3})$=0 which doesn't make sense. I'd say that the right solution should be:
$$\iint_{R^{2}} U(x,y,0)e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y)}dxdy$$
That comes if $\int _{R}dz=1$.
But I don't know how to proof it, someone knows? Thanks.

Comment: You want to evaluate $\iint_{R^{2}} U(x,y,0)e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y)}dxdy$ ? Then it is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_R g(k_1,k_2,k_3) dk_3$ (write $g(k_1,k_2,k_3)=\int_R V(k_1,k_2,z)e^{-i k_3 z}dz$ where $V(k_1,k_2,z) = \ldots$)

Comment: No, I want to proof that $\int_{R}dz=1$@reuns

Comment: $\int_a^b dz = b-a, \int_{R}dz=\infty$

Comment: Ok, but I have put z=0 so dz=0, so I wuold have said that $\int_{R}dz=0$ however it doesn't make sense. It should be results =1.@reuns

Comment: Nothing of what you wrote makes sense. It seems you don't understand integrals. What are you trying to solve

Comment: I ve edited the question. Hope that now it will be clearer, thanks for your help.@reuns

Comment: You can't "put $z=0$" in $g(k_{1},k_{2},k_{3})=\iiint_{R^{3}} U(x,y,z)e^{-i(k_1 x+k_2 y+ k_3 z)}dxdydz$. Did you mean $U(x,y,z) = U(x,y,0) $ ?

Comment: yes, I mean that @reuns

Comment: Find my $V$ above, if $U$ is constant in $z$ then so is $V$ thus its FT (in $z$) is a Dirac delta.